# How to debug a script put in module's config?

Tags: angularjs, oauth

My AngularJS project is working with an API. This API provides authentication tokens (Oauth): an `access_token` and a `refresh_token`.

Everytime an AngularJS request to the API returns a 401 error, it means that the `access_token` has expired and it needs to be refreshed by sending the `refresh_token` to a specific URL. To do that, [I followed this tutorial](http://engineering.talis.com/articles/elegant-api-auth-angular-js/).

But this is not working and I don't know why. I would like to debug the function placed into `.config(...)` but I don't know how to do that. `console.log()` and `$rootScope = ...` doesn't work here.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your browser's built-in debugger.

- Chrome: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging
- Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger
- Firebug: http://getfirebug.com/javascript
- IE: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699336%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Awesome ! But could you explain why the debugger is stopping at line 56 but not at line 58 or at line 60 please ?
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60521066/debug.jpg

Comment: The first function (lines 56-59) is called when a successful status code is received (codes 200-299) and the second function is called when an error code is returned (codes 400-499).  You are probably receiving an error code.

Comment: You're right, my endpoints were not at the right places. That said, I've tried everything and I still can't make the execution stop at lines 65 or 70. It's like the promise doesn't return neither a succes code or an error code... https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60521066/debug2.jpg

Comment: Your interceptor code is incorrect.  It should return an object with functions for 'request', 'requestError', 'response' and 'responseError', not a simple function.  See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Oh I see, the tutorial I was following is outdated ! Thanks for pointing that out ;)